# Integrating storybook with stencil (app starter)

Tags: typescript, storybook, stenciljs

I am trying to integrate story book with stencil, however, the stecil project was initailized with the app starter in `npm init stencil`. [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPHrL.png)

I have done some research on stencil with storybook but all of them seems to have initalized their project with the **component starter**. In posts like these https://ionic.io/blog/how-to-use-storybook-with-stencil, I was told to add `import {defineCustomElements} from '../loader'; defineCustomElements();` in `preview.js`. However, since there are no loader avalible with the app stencil starter, it doesn't actually work.

This is what my `stencil.config.ts` looks like.

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';
import { sass } from '@stencil/sass';

// https://stenciljs.com/docs/config

const prod: boolean = process.argv && process.argv.indexOf('--prod') > -1;
const apiEnv: string = prod ? 'prod' : 'dev';

export const config: Config = {
  env: {
    apiEnv: apiEnv
  },
  globalStyle: 'src/global/app.css',
  globalScript: 'src/global/app.ts',
  taskQueue: 'async',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'www',
      // comment the following line to disable service workers in production
      serviceWorker: null
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    sass({
      injectGlobalPaths: ['src/global/scss/app.scss']
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the app and component starters is the preconfigured output targets in `stencil.config.ts`. So you should be able to simply copy them over [from the component starter](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter/blob/main/stencil.config.ts):

```
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'stencil-starter-project-name',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: '../loader',
    },
    {
      type: 'dist-custom-elements',
    },
    {
      type: 'docs-readme',
    },
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: null, // disable service workers
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this method, and I get the following js error after running `stencil build`. I am using `@stencil/core v2.13.0`

Comment: `[ ERROR ]  Module format cjs does not support top-level await. Use the "es" or "system" output formats rather. at error
           (/Users/hahafhaha/Desktop/code/work-fall-2022/storybook-test/big-shooter-golf-stencil/node_modules/@stencil/core/compiler/stencil.js:25523:26)
           at Chunk$2.render
           (/Users/hahafhaha/Desktop/code/work-fall-2022/storybook-test/big-shooter-golf-stencil/node_modules/@stencil/core/compiler/stencil.js:31536:14)
at async generateRollupOutput`